# Flash copy to clipboard bug

Tags: javascript, flash, copy

I am trying to apply Copy to clipboard to my website, but there seems to be a bug because the text is not getting copied on my website.

[Clipboard.swf](http://bravo9.com/journal/copying-text-into-the-clipboard-with-javascript-in-firefox-safari-ie-opera-292559a2-cc6c-4ebf-9724-d23e8bc5ad8a/) : Using this for copying

My website: [FileLnx](http://filelnx.com/?setskin=filelnx-1) (please upload then click on a text field for copy)

Comment: This sounds like a security restriction rather than a bug. Please show more details about what you are doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should answer your question:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer10_security_changes.html#head31

> In Flash Player 9, ActionScript could
>   set data on the system Clipboard at
>   any time. With Flash Player 10, the
>   System.setClipboard() method may be
>   successfully called only through
>   ActionScript that originates from user
>   interaction. This includes actions
>   such as clicking the mouse or using
>   the keyboard. This user interaction
>   requirement also applies to the new
>   ActionScript 3.0
>   Clipboard.generalClipboard.setData()
>   and
>   Clipboard.generalClipboard.setDataHandler()
>   methods.

Comment: Can you please suggest some other swf? I searched a lot but none worked for me.

Comment: @Shishant: Why don't you pre-select and focus some text and tell the user to press CTRL+C?